# why is my blackberry device not able to access data from an external domain whereas my BB simulator does?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks, phonegap-build

I have a cordova (phonegap) Blackberry app that receives data from an external domain. Now, the problem is it doesn't work on my Blackberry device (has OS 7) but works fine within -
1. Android app (any version)
2. Windows phone 8 app
3. Blackberry device's default web-browser.

I researched over and understood that the config.xml file has to be edited with inclusions of the domain name in `<access>` tag.. 
So I did the below -

```
 <access subdomains="true" uri="*" />

  <access subdomains="true" uri="http://192.168.0.103:81/">
  <feature id="blackberry.app" version="1.0.0.0" required="true"/>
  <feature id="blackberry.invoke" version="1.0.0.0" required="true"/>
  <feature id="phonegap" required="true"/>
  <feature id="cordova" required="true"/>  
  </access>
```

I am not sure why my device is not able to get access through that domain.
I've also disabled firewall on my BB device.

Here is my code from which am receiving my data-

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('#restaurantsList').click(function(){

   var myList = '';
     var url = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81/xxxx/retrieve_all.php"; 
     $.getJSON(url, function(json) {    
                $.each(json, function(i, v) {    
                 myList += '<li id='+v.fb_sno+' onClick="getRestauDet('+ v.fb_sno +')"><img src="'+v.fb_img+'"/><h2>' + v.fb_name + '</h2><h3>'+ v.fb_type + '</h3><h4>'+ v.fb_location + '</h4></a></li>';                                 
                 });
                 $("#descriptionTitle").html("Food & Beverages");
                 $("#listOfItems").html(myList);
                 $('[id=listOfItems]').listview('refresh');
                 });    
                 });        
});
```

Comment: When you say recieves data I assume you mean via AJAX ?

Comment: @jeffheifetz- am adding my code in my question

Comment: What version of cordova?

Comment: @jeffheifetz - the Cordova version is 2.8.0

Comment: @jeffheifetz - any clue on why this is happening? :(

Comment: I really wish I did, but in truth those access tags should cover it. The other possibility is related to the IT policies activated on the device